# How to display wrong password error message from javascript MDL textfield

Tags: javascript, html, material-design-lite

I am trying to write a login page but I am stuck at displaying the message in `mdl-textfield__error` when the password is wrong. My html code is as follows:

```
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="mdl-grid">
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
        <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--6dp">
            <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
                <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Title</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
                <form action="#">
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="username" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Email</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
                        <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="userpass" />
                        <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Şifre</label>
                        <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Şifre yanlış. Tekrar deneyin.</span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <button id="sign-in" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Giriş Yap</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to check if the password is incorrect? Or how to display an error message? Are you checking if the password is incorrect, do you have an ajax request?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I am asking how to display an error message. I am checking password correctness with firebase in JS code.

Comment: Did the solution below solve the issue?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `is-invalid` and `is-dirty` classes to the parent `.mdl-textfield` element.

```html
<link href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-color--grey-100">
<main class="mdl-layout__content">
  <div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-shadow--6dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-color--primary mdl-color-text--white">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">OLUF 17 Giriş</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <form action="#">
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="username" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="username">Email</label>
          </div>
          <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield is-dirty is-invalid">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="userpass" />
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="userpass">Şifre</label>
            <span class="mdl-textfield__error">Şifre yanlış. Tekrar deneyin.</span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <button id="sign-in" class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">Giriş Yap</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```